# Unable to update macOS Monterey; check updates only shows Ventura upgrade

Tags: macos, software-update

I am not able to update my macOS, from version 12.6.2 → 12.6.3. I am using a MacBook, with an Apple silicon chip. I am hoping to avoid a Ventura upgrade at this time, and to update Monterey soon (irrespective of its possible staged update roll-out). This is due to the unusually substantial [security updates](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213604) contained in this release.

In particular, Software Update only shows the upgrade option (currently to 13.2, which I am not ready to undertake). I had this exact same issue when updating from 12.6.1, but eventually after a few weeks it showed the option to update (no config. changes before nor since, and did not have to restart to see it).

I do not have Content Caching enabled, on any devices.

N.B. I understand the need to utilize the "More Info…" dialogue, and have used it to update before. Indeed, I used it earlier this same week, to update to the latest version of Safari, though that dialogue still had not listed macOS 12.6.3 as an option, despite its having been co-released. The "More Info…" dialogue no longer shows for me at all (i.e., the update option for Monterey is non-existent, not merely hidden by the Ventura upgrade option).

Additionally, checking for updates via `sudo softwareupdate -l`, incorrectly returns "No new software available".  `sudo softwareupdate  --list-full-installers` correctly lists "macOS Monterey, Version: 12.6.3, Size: 12115350KiB, Build: 21G419",  as one of 7 options, but nothing I do appears to be able to actually install it that way. Finally, attempting to install 12.6.3 via the App. Store, after successfully downloading it and following its dialogs, eventually yields an error (despite repeated attempts).

I have already tried restarting normally (re-opening open applications), to ensure that this is not the result of some stuck process. I have also attempted to reset the Software Update caches, via the below command, and then checking Software Update again, to no avail.

```
sudo rm -f /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist
```

---

This issue remains outstanding, over 2 weeks after the release of 12.6.3. It is accordingly no longer reasonable that the update is not being offered to me due to staggered updates.

---

Can anyone think of a way to solve this *without my having to attempt multiple system restarts, nor enter safe mode, nor use Recovery*. (I am not willing to lose all my open applications and window configurations, at this time. Please note that this can still be accomplished upon an ordinary reboot for an update, via the "Restart… → Reopen windows when logging back in" modal dialogue option.)

Comment: Just stumbled across https://github.com/ninxsoft/Mist, might help.

Comment: @nohillside Appreciate the link—thanks! Still hope to diagnose the underlying issue, but nice to know about that useful tool.

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution is to wait a week. Updates are staggered, so 25 million people aren't offered them all at once, swamping the servers.

You should check the 'more info' option, though, if you haven't already - because whilst Apple really, *really* want you to upgrade to Ventura, if you push a little harder you might find the Monterey update sneaking in under the door…

[image]

[image]

It's also wise to not let *everything* be automatic

[image]

Comment: My lack of an ability to update via all the other methods I described suggests there is another issue (perhaps some inability to correctly fetch the available new version or something else).